# Which files affected by CRC errors on NTFS?

Tags: windows, ntfs, crc

I have CRC errors on my NTFS USB HDD and would like to know which files have been affected.

I'm doing a `chkdsk /F /X /R`, so far, it doesn't list any files.

Is there a tool/command to map out which files are affected?

UPDATE:

This will sound complicated, but I'm in the midst of moving out of the Windows ecosystem, and doing it progressively so that life functions as per normal.

1. I have a USB NTFS formatted drive previously plugged into Windows 10
2. I moved it to Debian and used `ntfs-3g` to mount it
3. It is exposed back to Windows via CIFS so that "life goes on"
4. In a routine reading of the files, my Windows app reported `Error: cyclic redundancy check failed` on 1 specific file, the function used was `ReadFileAsync`
5. I went into Debian to try and copy that file, it also reported read/write error or something, so I pulled out the drive from Debian and moved it back to Windows for a `chkdsk`
6. Before `chkdsk`, I tried 1 last time to copy the file on CLI, still failed, can't recall the exact error
7. When I saw the request for more info here, I terminated my `chkdsk` to try and retrieve the exact error for #5, however, copying that same file now was a success
8. Pretty sure it wasn't just a dirty flag, I ran Debian's `ntfsfix` to be sure of it.

Comment: Who/what says there are CRC errors. NTFS does not checksum files. Add info to the question, edit it, make it complete so we can understand it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a tool/command to map out which files are affected?

- First try get an idea about the drive's health using SMART
- Then, I'd probably just byte the bullet and clone the entire drive. If the drive's health status is alarming use for example ddrescue

Any sectors that posed a problem can then be mapped to files using for example NFI.exe

Example:

```
C:\>nfi \device\harddisk0 40000
NTFS File Sector Information Utility.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1999. All rights reserved.    

***Physical sector 40000 (0x9c40) is in file number 146 on drive C.
\demo\PHASE2~1.PPT
$STANDARD_INFORMATION (resident)
$FILE_NAME (resident)
$FILE_NAME (resident)
$SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR (resident)
$DATA (nonresident)
physical sectors 39968-40198 (0x9c20-0x9d06)
```

- As a rule of thumb I'd not expose a NTFS formatted drive to both Windows and Linux (2 captains on one ship problem). So again, migrate data and be done with it.

NFI references: [http://www.users.on.net/~fzabkar/temp/ph3nfi.htm](http://www.users.on.net/%7Efzabkar/temp/ph3nfi.htm)